# Same height (specified by a responsive image) for two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to display two divs side by side. The left one contains a responsive image, the second one text. Their width is 50% each. What I want is

- the image to keep it's aspect ratio,
- the text to keep it's font size,
- both divs to have roughly the same height,
- the text to be shortened as necessary (probably *text-overflow:ellipsis* for the right hand div)

Is this possible? Can I make the right hand div not grow any higher than the left one?

The snippet contains a simplified version of my current markup, but that's not set in stone.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.intro-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/170" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="intro-wrapper">
    long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here. long text here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `text-overflow` bit and the height limit is likely to make it so that it requires javascript.

Comment: Yes, getting the text container "cut off" at the image height is relatively easy (wrap text into an additional container, and position that absolute within `.intro-wrapper`, with `inset: 0` and `overflow: hidden`) - but it will be a "hard" cut-off, that might even cut the letters on the last line in half, and `text-overflow` will not work in this situation, not with free-flowing text (you'd need to apply `white-space: pre` or similar.)